# Abnormal integral

Tags: analysis

Suppose that function $f(x)$ be defined on $[a, \infty)$. We know that if abnormal integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x$ converges, then $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x=0$. Conversely, if $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x=0$, can we get $\int_a^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x$ convergence?

Comment: $\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_A^{\infty} f(x)dx$ does not make sense when  you don't know that $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ exists.

Comment: Do you mean *improper* ?

Comment: Consider $a=0,\,f(x)=1/(x+x^2)$.

Comment: For $,a=0, f(x)=1/(x+x^2)$ does not defined on $[0,\infty)$, $f(0)$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. Acoording to your comments , $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x=0$ holds only on the condition that $\int_a^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x$ exists. Or else,  $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x=0$ does not make sense. Is that so?

Comment: That is true but you restate the result using only integrals over finite intervals and that is what I have done in  my answer.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. Only on the condition that infinite integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x$ converge, the limit $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^\infty f(x)\mbox{d}x=0$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\int_A^{b} f(x)dx$ exists (whnever $A<B$) and tends to $0$ as $A$ and $B$ tend to $\infty$ then $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ exists. This is proved by observing that $(\int_a^{x_n} f(x)dx)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent, for any sequence $x_n \to \infty$ and the limit is independent of $(x_n)$. However, the question, as stated, does not make sense as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: You say the Cauchy convergence criterion, I know this theorem. Thank you.